# A spinning image in kivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm making a phone app that should have a spinning image at the center. So I made it like this:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        from threading import Timer
        Timer(3.0, self.rotate).start()
    def rotate(self):
        from time import sleep
        while True:
            while self.root.current == 'mainscreen':
                self.root.get_screen('mainscreen').ids.spin.angle -= 1
                sleep(0.01)
```

And this is the .kv file:

```
'''
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    SecondScreen:
<IMG@Image>:
    angle: 45
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            origin: self.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'mainscreen'

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height

        MDToolbar:
            title: "My App"

        IMG:
            angle: 0
            id: spin
            source: 'file.png'
            allow_stretch: True

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'secondscreen'
'''
```

The function `rotate` is suposed to make the image spin. And it actually works, it keeps spinning, but whenever I resize the window it stops spinning. I have no Idea why this is happening. Can someone tell me what to do? If there is a better way to make the image spin I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Animation` to do that by animating the `angle`. Something like:

```
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.stop_anim = False
        Clock.schedule_once(self.rotate)

    def rotate(self, *args):
        if self.stop_anim:
            return
        spinner = self.root.get_screen('mainscreen').ids.spin
        spinner.angle = 0
        self.anim = Animation(angle=360)
        self.anim.bind(on_complete=self.rotate)
        self.anim.start(spinner)
```